# Bufferedreader blocking call in java 8

Tags: java-8, bufferedreader

Is there a way to block bufferedreader in java 8 if there is no data in input source then bufferedreader wait untill data is available ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your scenario / use case ?

Comment: I have a consumer thread which reads data from input.txt file and generates a output accordingly. the requirement is something like If there is no data in input source then consumer thread shall wait untill data is available. So I thought if there any way for the buffered reader to wait until data is available then it will solve my problem. My question is how to handle this situation in java 8 ?